# Does the derivative of $f(x) = 2x^2 |x|$ exist at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Maybe an elementary question. I'm helping some kids I know study for their calculus exam, and somehow I'm confused about this and I can't figure out a way to explain the answer to them? So, from what I think, if you take the derivative for values greater than zero and less than zero, you get:
$$\frac{df}{dx} = 6x^2$$ and
$$\frac{df}{dx} = -6x^2$$
respectively, right?
But, is this differentiable at $x=0$? Wouldn't the limits of both the sides be different?

Comment: $ \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= 2x|x| \to ?$ as $x \to 0.$

Comment: Would you not have to check both left hand and right hand limits? Because of the fact that you have the $|x|$ term, which isn't differentiable at 0?

Comment: @chocodierdre you are thinking about taking an "extra" derivative. The limit *is* the derivative. Taking a limit, all we require is continuity. $|x|$ is certainly continuous at $0$

Answer (score 2):

That function is differentiable at $0$; the derivative there is $0$. You can see that clearly in a picture.

To prove it from the definition of the derivative, note that for
$h \ne 0$ the difference quotient is
$$
\frac{f(0+h) -f(0)}{h} = \frac{2h^2|h|}{h} = 2h|h|
$$
which has limit $0$ as $h$ approaches $0$.

In fact, the derivative as a function is itself differentiable. That's not true for $f(x) = x|x|$.

Comment: Ahh right. Okay, so I've asked the other two people who responded to this as well, but do right hand and left hand limits not matter when you're looking at taking this derivative? Again, because you have $x^2 |x|$, so when you differentiate this, does taking both one sided limits not matter?

Comment: No, you don't have to check left and right limits. There is just one limit for the difference quotient. What you have observed is that the formula for the derivative is different on each half of the horizontal axis. I suggest you draw the graphs of $f(x) = x|x|$ and its derivative. The derivative has a corner, so is not itself differentiable.

Comment: Oh, right, okay. I think I understand. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Let $f(x)=2x^2\left| x \right|$.

Since $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}2x\left| x\right| = 0$$

exist, $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Right, but, like I've asked above to someone else as well. Would you not have to check both left hand and right hand limits? Because of the fact that you have the $|x|$ term, which isn't differentiable at 0?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand how differentiability works. We have two functions $f,$ $g,$ defined by $f(x)=|x|$ and $g(x)=2x^2|x|$ respectively, so that $g(x)=2x^2f(x).$ You are correct in pointing out that $f$ is not differentiable at $0.$ However, that does not imply $g$ is not differentiable either. I do not know why you are making this leap in logic. The only requirement for $g$ to be differentiable at $0$ is for $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}$$ to exist. Whether $f$ is differentiable at $0$ or not is not relevant. We know that $g(0)=0,$ so $$g'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}2xf(x).$$ So as long as this latter limit exists, the differentiability, or lack thereof, of $f$ at $0$ does not matter. Does this limit exist? That is the only question you need to answer to determine whether $g$ is differentiable at $0$ or not.

I suspect the reason you are getting so caught up on the non-differentiability of $f$ at $0$ is because it seems to me you are thinking that the product $f\cdot{g}$ can only be differentiable at $0$ if both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $0.$ That is just not true, though. Suppose $f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=0.$ Then $$(f\cdot{g})'(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{x}$$ must exist. Now, if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, then it certainly is true that the limit exists. But such a strong condition is not necessary for the limit to exist. It only requires that one of the two functions be differentiable at $0,$ and that the limit for the other function exist. If $g$ is differentiable at $0,$ then $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)}{x}$$ must exist. So if $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$$ also exists, then that is more than sufficient for $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{x}=\left[\lim_{x\to0}f(x)\right]\left[\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)}{x}\right]=g'(0)\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$$ to exist and be true.